# How do you delay the launch of an application in Windows 7 at startup?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I'd like to delay the launch of some startup apps to give it some time to load the other ones before the one I want.

Answer (score 18):

The Task Scheduler in the newer versions of Windows has got quite an overhaul. One of its improvements is to delay start a task. Simply set it to execute your 'apps' ON LOGON with different delays.

Comment: Task Scheduler sets low priorities to processes by default. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427142/is-there-any-way-for-a-win2k8-scheduled-task-to-have-normal-priority-io

Answer (score 8):

[Startup Delayer](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/startdelay.html)

Startup Delayer is a free program tha  allows you to configure which programs to start first and which ones to delay when your computer is rebooted. You can set a custom delay for each one, even drag the visual display graph which shows you exactly how your programs are starting and allows you to easily modify the order or adjust delay times.

Comment: Startup Delayer is exactly the program needed. All startup programs can be spread out in time so that they start more smoothly or at desired intervals. www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startdelay

Comment: This seems to have a lot more options than Task Scheduler, like CPU & Disk Monitoring based delays, internet connection check & etc. Pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

Type Windows + R

Your run dialog pops up.

Enter: services.msc

Find your service that you want to delay

Right click on it, select Properties

Under Startup type: select Automatic (Delayed Start)

There you go.

Comment: This is for services only, not programs.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to delay for 1min some application at PC startup after the network connection...

I used standard build in Windows **Task scheduler**.

Its simply- **create task**, and fill up all necessary pages - General, Triggers, Actions, Settings.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to do it the good ol MS DOS way
create a start.bat file in C:\ with

```
rem launching Thunderbird and Skype in 44 seconds
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 44000 > nul
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird"
start thunderbird.exe
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 78000 > nul
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\" Skype.exe /min
```

Then create a shortcut to it and put the shortcut into the

```
c:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

folder

Answer (score 1):

Leverage windows task scheduler, screenshot shows delay option you need

1. *Create a task* in the scheduler
2. Go to the *Triggers* tab and click *New*
3. Set *Begin the task* to *At log on*
4. Check *Delay task for* and enter anything between seconds to hours

[windows task scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/446Hr.png)

Comment: If the image link breaks, your answer is no longer valid. Please edit your answer to include all of the relevant information. The image can be left as illustration.