# Any Idea what this is

Tags: boot

Anyone have any idea what this icon / application is (link below)? It flashes up for less than a second when i first boot up on a windows 10 machine, sometime its so quick i don't even see it.

It always appears just above the windows start icon. I've turned everything off in start up, and tried in safe mode as well, but still there. Run Malwarebytes, etcs, but nothing found.

[image: 1]

Comment: Look as though it is wanting to __install__ a software package of somekind. Or are you talking about the blue icon, "Outlook", with mail? Try and right-click on it as it may freeze it.

Comment: If you right-click on the taskbar you can choose __Taskbar settings__ > _Select which taskbars appear on the taskbar_ you may be able to get an answer of which program is appearing.

Comment: Its the white box with three different icons in it ( a PC, a box, and a cross). I've tried to click it or grab it, but nothing happens, and it flashes up so quick its hard to get it. Just checked the taskbar setting, but nothing in there i can see, everything is set to off pretty much. I never seen it before on any PC or laptop i have had, hence my curiosity.

Comment: You should edit your question with the "Its the white box with..." It is helpful information. Please inform us if you find the answer with an Answer. You can answer your own questions here.

Answer (score -1):

I do not recognize the icon...  It could be anything.  However, you should download and use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), which is part of Microsoft's [Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) suite of tools.  There are a lot more startup programs than what you in the Start folder.  Autoruns might be able to tell you what is running this icon.

Comment: Ok, will give it a go.

Comment: Better still, see my answer as [there are at least 17 locations from where programs can be started](https://superuser.com/questions/1047598/want-to-delay-startup-of-program-but-cant-find-it-in-task-scheduler/1047629#1047629)