# Why is some process always launched at startup of my Windows-10 PC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, task-scheduler

I have a program, called "Product Server.exe", being launched when I (re)start my Windows-10 computer.

Launching `MsConfig` brings me to the task manager, where the "Startup" tab shows me something I don't understand:

[image]

(I have no idea what that "Program" is about, but I don't dare disabling it. You never know it's needed for something and I do not want to risk making my computer unusable.)

When I check the task scheduler, I don't see the mentioned process, as you can see:

```
Command Prompt> schtasks /query /V | findstr /I "Product"

(empty line)
```

As you see: no result.

**Edit: added 'wmic' result:**
Asking the same (or a similar) question, using `wmic`, gives the same result:

```
Command Prompt> wmic Startup list | findstr /I "Product"

(empty line)
```

So, I'm left with two related questions:

- How can I know what that "Program" entry in the "Startup" tab of my task manager means?
- In case that "Program" entry does not correspond with the startup of "Product Server.exe", where can I go for disabling it?

Thanks in advance

**Edit2:**

Thanks to [Daniel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b), I now know that the "Program" entry in my task manager is not the cause of the issue: there are more columns in task manager, explaining this, as you can see from this new screenshot:

[image]

=> The "Program" entry is about Teams, another program.

Still I have the question: why is "Product Server.exe" started at startup of my computer?

Comment: I don't quite get what makes you look at Task Scheduler. // You can enable another column in Task Manager, "Startup type" ("Command line" is also of interest). It will tell you how the software is made to start. // I have "Program" too, by the way. It is a broken entry created by Office 365 Pro Plus.

Comment: Use more extended programs. I recommend [AutoRuns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

Comment: @DanielB: thanks for your comment. Now I already know that that "Program" entry is not the cause of that "Product Server.exe" being launched at startup, I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: See my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1047629)

Comment: @DavidPostill: thanks to your answer, I have found my program in the list of Windows services, this by using "Autoruns". I've upvoted your answer and the corresponding question and I've voted to close my question as being a duplicate.