# Problems with duplicate startup items in Task Manager

Tags: windows-10, boot, task-manager

I have problems regarding the startup list on my Task Manager in Windows 10, as seen in the picture below:

[image: taskmanager]

You can see the duplicated entries that I marked in red circle. I have tried to find the source of these entries, including searching for them using RegEdit (in the usual startup entries mentioned online) but until now I am still unable to find their location... does anyone know what might be adding these duplicate entries?

Any response for this problem is really appreciated, thx.

Comment: autoruns https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: I have tried that too but unfortunately those duplicate values are not listed in there as well...

Comment: Does [windows 10 - Want to delay startup of program but can't find it in Task Scheduler - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1047598/want-to-delay-startup-of-program-but-cant-find-it-in-task-scheduler/1047629#1047629) answer your question?

Comment: nope, I have tried using those applications on your link and just like I said, I have gone through the registry responsible for startup mentioned on internet, including registry location on your link...it is strange I cannot find those startup items even in registry editor..is it stored somewhere else?

Comment: In Task Manager, Startups, right-click the header and add the column of "Command line". Take a screenshot again for us, to see if this is a true duplicate. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Check if they're being started under different credentials. E.G., there is a <user> Startup folder, and an All Users Startup folder

Comment: @harrymc Thx for the enlightment.. Yep you are right..the command for those two are for different instances...but is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

After adding the "Command line" column to Task Manager in the Startups tab,
by right-click on the header it was found that the command-lines are different
for these "duplicates".

It's quite normal in Windows for the same processes to support
different modes of execution that are dictated by command-line options.

For example, the Task Scheduler Configuration Tool is actually
[schtasks.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html),
which is a very central task in Windows with lots of functions.

See also [What is schtasks.exe?](https://www.file.net/process/schtasks.exe.html)