# Is there a way to know how much time a program takes at my computer's startup?

Tags: windows-10, autostart

There are some programs which automatically start when I turn on my Windows 10. However, I would like to speed up the time it takes my PC to be ready. My solution is to find which software slows down the machine at the start, and delay this software's start. In other words, I want to delay the start of less necessary software.

Though, I am not sure I should spend my time on all this. I have an SSD and I think it is very fast. And if some program takes only milliseconds to start, then I will save my time and effort.

So, **how do I know the time it takes a specific program to start at autostart?** Here is a list of programs that start automatically when I turn on my PC (however, I cannot see the exact time in seconds or milliseconds - that is what I want to see).

[image]

Comment: Your image link appears to be broken from my side at least. Do some searching on Windows 10 boot logging and see if that'll help you any.

Comment: I remember using some Windows SDK tool in Win7 which showed very detailed time graphs with what process starts and ends when. Can't find it right now, but maybe someone knows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/969549/booting-windows-10-spends-too-long

Comment: I think the rollback was not necessary.

Comment: Looks like this question is rewritten from British English to American English. [That is not a necessary edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)

Comment: "programme" is not correct even in British English when referring to computer software.

Comment: @Hohmannfan there were other things in the edit too such as putting the image in the body rather than using a link.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

On the same tab in the Task Manager, right click one of the column headers and select **CPU at startup** from the list that appears.  This will display the total CPU time in milliseconds that the application used during startup.

Example:

[image: My Task Manager]

Comment: This doesn't work in my system. All items in the "CPU at startup" column say "0 ms", and the "impact" column says "Not measured".

Comment: @MartinArgerami if it's not measured, then it makes sense not to have a CPU time displayed. I don't think you can change it to make the application be measured either. At least I don't know if you can

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I found out that Skype takes 3.378ms, Punto Switcher is 988ms, Logitech Gaming Framework is 512ms. 
I will let Skype start as fast as possible as I need my messages there delivered very fast.
The other 3 programs should be postponed using Task Scheduler which allows to run a program at startup with a specified delay. The only problem is that Task Scheduler does not seem to be doing its task reliably. I created a task there to delay the start of my uTorrent by 1 min, and it worked for about a month. Then it stopped working - though i can start uTorrent manually.

Comment: So, i decided to find another way. There is a question about how to delay specified programs and one user suggested using an MS DOS way create a start.bat file. I still don't understand how to do it, as I am a PC noob who does not know that MS DOS code. Can anybody help me run those 3 programs with delay? PS it would be better not to install any autostart management apps.

Comment: @SergeyLarin you may want to try asking in another question.  What was the question you found about delaying programs? Can you link it?

Comment: @Timmy Jim Yes, I will start a new question when i make sure i know how to ask it :-) meanwhile, the MS-DOS way of making programs start at system's start-up is here: https://superuser.com/questions/167933/how-do-you-delay-the-launch-of-an-application-in-windows-7-at-startup

it was answered by user3049273. He proposed creating a .bat file.

Comment: There's a plethora of tabs in Startup that I wasn't even aware of (CPU load, disk load, etc.). Yes, this answer definitely does work for my system (W10 1607).

Answer (score 1):

Performance Monitor is a simple yet powerful visualization tool for viewing performance data, both in real time and from log files. With it, you can examine performance data in a graph, histogram, or report. You can use the Performance Monitor like so:

```
perfmon /report
```

Comment: I tried to include their image when tells the story, but the image import tool wouldn't allow it.  I hate to just post links but I was pressed for time and these are accurate.  Perhaps I can go back and get a screenshot instead.  But if you just do it you will see what I mean.  Perfmon is confusing; hence my suggestion that you let it generate a report.

Comment: I ran the command you advised me, but I could not find the time which specific programs take at my PC's start. How do I find this time using this Perfmon?

Answer (score 0):

When your program is started at startup, does this mean it's configured in the "task scheduler" (part of settings)? In that case, you can look there to see when it has started, and in the "History" tab you can see the whole lifecycle (including the "Action completed" timestamp.

Comment: only one program uses Task Scheduler. The others were set to start at Windows start-up in their own settings. Although, I tried to find the startup time even for that one praogram. Guess what? The function was disabled.