# Start a task an hour after Windows started

Tags: windows-10

I only found answers to start a task every hour or similar, but my need is different.

My mother-in-law's PC is quite slow to start, so I think it would be a good idea to postpone things that are non-essential.

Can I put programs in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` so that they are started an hour later?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/167933/how-do-you-delay-the-launch-of-an-application-in-windows-7-at-startup

Comment: @Run5k except for the OS, everything is the same. We can close this one if we add the win10 tag to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a scheduled task that runs at logon, and in the advanced settings of the trigger specify a delay of an hour or so.

To open the task scheduler, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `control schedtasks` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

In the left panel, select Task Scheduler Library, and then right click on it. You can either select *Create a basic task* immediately, or create a new folder first, if you want to keep things a bit organized.

You'll need to finish the task creation wizard, and on the last page, select 'Open the properties window of this task' before clicking *Finish*.

In the Properties Window, select the Triggers tab, edit the *At Login* trigger, and set the delay.